# PHP Memory Exhausted Error

Tags: php, fatal-error

I know this might sound very stupid but I am a total noob in programming and I am very frustrated about this error.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7059335 bytes) in C:\TOM Files\wamp\www\program_exer_1\index.php on line 2

I want to know what it means and what are the possible solutions for this. Please help.

Comment: might u have encountered a never ending loop, show some code then someone might help

Comment: It means your program attempted to use up more than 128MB of memory. That is *a lot* for a PHP script. You are almost certainly attempting to load a large amount of data (database records, or file contents) into memory at once. It should be pretty obvious to you where your program does something like this. Rewrite it to process the results a few at a time, instead of loading them all into memory up front.

Comment: Nice comment, Jon. Consider turning into an answer.

Comment: Its already solved. Yeah, very big data. 76 tables. I idi the answer by Christopher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the memory limit of PHP either in `php.ini` if you have access by editing the following line:

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

Or by adding this line to specific scripts:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
```

Comment: If you read the question more carefully, you will see that the memory limit is already at 128M.

Comment: is the ini_set in the config?

Comment: @Jon I am a total noob. I know its memory problem but I don't know where to locate that...

Comment: It helped.. It worked!!! I did change it in the php.ini and set it to memory_limit = 256M.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this caused in several occasions by corruption in MySQL tables. How that causes this particular fault, I have no idea. But just for good measure, you may want to check and repair your MySQL db.

```
mysqlcheck -rA
```

Comment: I solved it. Just changed the memory_limit in php.ini. Anyway, I'll consider your advice on my future learning. Thanks bro for the additional info...